# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

Попробовал связать `asp.net mvc` приложение с oracle db.

Установил [ODAC 12c Release 4 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/partners/campaign/utilsoft-086879.html)

Далее задал настройки для tnsnames.ora:

```
    dvd =
    (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = **какойтоайпи**)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL) 
    )
  )
```

В самом приложении подключил пакет [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/12.1.22/).

Приложение содержит в себе три проекта: web, bll и dal.

В дал лежит сам edmx файл. Через `entity framework` идет `db first model`, 
то бишь, сущности создаем в соответствии с базой.

Я подключился в server explorer из vs 2015.
Указал правильный tnsnames.ora файл и все у меня заработало,
но далее, когда сделал паблишь на удаленный сервер, приложение стало выкидывать ошибку:

> FATAL System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Подскажи в чем проблема, и как с этим бороться?

Comment: Вы уверены, что на удалённом сервере используется тот же tnsnames.ora, что и локально? Он включён в сборку?

Comment: в сборку tnsnames.ora не включен, если честно даже не знаю как его правильно так добавить. просто пока над проектом работали, tnsnames.ora хранился в app/../Admin я установил на сервер [ссылка]( ODAC 12c Release 4 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio )[ссылка] и в его и после установки сгенерились файла app/.../Admin/ и там уже указал конфиги tnsnames.ora

Comment: Надо куда-то в эту сторону смотреть. Клиент будет использовать тот tnsnames.ora, на который ему указывают настройки среды, в которой он запускается. Пока было локально - это были настройки проекта. На удалённом сервере - зависит от того, что там за среда. Если это какой-то сервер приложений, то может у него свои настройки есть?

Comment: сервер на котором лежит база одна и та же, то есть саму базу не меняли, пока над проектом работали локально тоже подрубались к удаленной базе, она лежит на отдельном сервере

Answer (score 2):

Причина ошибки:

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Клиент не может найти к заданному идентификатору соединения соответствующие ему параметры: 1) идентификатора в файле нет, или 2) поиск идёт не в том файле.

Простое правило [синтаксиса кофигурационных файлов](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netrf/syntax-rules-configuration-files.html#GUID-C1E7C97B-FF0A-4174-BC09-6F1B09B0B6E1), tnsnames.ora в их числе:

> **Any keyword in a configuration file that begins a parameter** that includes one or more keyword-value pairs **must be in the far left column of a line**. If it is indented by one or more spaces, then it is interpreted as a continuation of the previous line.

То есть, идентификатор `dvd` в вопросе не будет найден, так как перед ним пробелы.

---

Всегда можно проверить соединение без поиска в tnsnames.ora, задавая его параметры напрямую. Параметры по-умолчанию, например `PORT=1521`, задавать не обязательно. Например:

```
$ sqlplus user/pass@\
    "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=**какойтоайпи**))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)))"
```